# Json Response NULL from webservice

Tags: iphone, asp.net, json, web-services

hi i m Using Web service in IPhone i am Getting Json Response null when i use  loacal server to Run i m getting Response 
this is my Code

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

this is my link to call webservice

**http://tagcheckin.com/Webservice/Webservice1.asmx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a WebService from AJAX, you need to decorate the service with the `[ScriptService]` attribute

If you want to access you service using `GET`:

- Add the `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]` attribute to the web method

  ```
  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
  public string HelloWorld()
  ```
- Add the following configuration to your web.config right under `<system.web>` (server config where the web service lives).

  ```
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet" />
      <add name="HttpPost" />
    </protocols>
  </webServices>
  ```

As a reminder, when using XML services you need to access the returned object as:

```
success: function (m) {
    $res.append("Message: " + m.d);
}
```

Comment: where to add [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]  ????

Comment: i have edited mu code as u adviced but still in IPhone they r getting null Response in Android They are getting Response so